# How to shorten repeating code with html function and return tags in jquery

Tags: jquery, repeat, minify

I'm just learning how to shorten repeating code. Perhaps someone can point me to where I can learn more about this?

I'm trying to shorten my following code. I managed to shorten using the var dph.

*For example: how can I shorten the following commands:*

html(function () {

return $(this).html().replace(

**The code I'm trying to shrink/minify:**

```
  setTimeout(
function() 
{
      var dph = $("#description-paste-here");
      dph.html(function () {
        return $(this).html().replace("Please see the valuation for more information.", "This item comes with a valuation.", "For more information on this or any other item you may have seen please feel free to send me an email and I will respond as soon as possible.", "");
      });
      dph.html(function () {
        return $(this).html().replace("<br><br>For more information on this or any other item you may have seen please feel free to send me an email and I will respond as soon as possible.", "");
      });
      dph.html(function () {
        var findSHDL = $('#thestoreshdl').html();
        return $(this).html().replace("00002340", findSHDL);
      });
      dph.html(function () {
        var findStore = $('#thestorelocation').html();
        return $(this).html().replace("East Victoria Park", findStore);
      });
      dph.html(function () {
        var findHours = $('#thestorehours').html();
        return $(this).html().replace("9:30am – 5pm Monday to Saturday", findHours);
      });
}, 100);
```

Many thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly note that `replace()` only accepts two arguments, the string to search for and the string to replace it with. The first example provides multiple arguments which will be ignored. I presume this is just a typo.

With regards to your question, the simplest way to achieve your goal would be to hold the search.replace values in an array of objects which can be iterated through.

In addition, as you're working on the HTML of the same element in each function, you can join them all in to a single action. Try this:

```js
let replacements = [{
  target: 'Please see the valuation for more information. This item comes with a valuation. For more information on this or any other item you may have seen please feel free to send me an email and I will respond as soon as possible.',
  replacement: ''
}, {
  target: '<br><br>For more information on this or any other item you may have seen please feel free to send me an email and I will respond as soon as possible.',
  replacement: ''
}, {
  target: '00002340',
  replacement: $('#thestoreshdl').html()
}, {
  target: 'East Victoria Park',
  replacement: $('#thestorelocation').html()
}, {
  target: '9:30am – 5pm Monday to Saturday',
  replacement: $('#thestorehours').html()
}];

setTimeout(() => {
  $("#description-paste-here").html((i, h) => {
    replacements.forEach(o => h = h.replace(o.target, o.replacement));
    return h;
  });
}, 100);
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="description-paste-here">
  Please see the valuation for more information. This item comes with a valuation. For more information on this or any other item you may have seen please feel free to send me an email and I will respond as soon as possible.
  <br><br>For more information on this or any other item you may have seen please feel free to send me an email and I will respond as soon as possible.
  <br /><br /> 00002340
  <br /><br /> East Victoria Park
  <br /><br /> 9:30am – 5pm Monday to Saturday
</div>

<div class="hidden" id="thestoreshdl">The store HDL...</div>
<div class="hidden" id="thestorelocation">The location...</div>
<div class="hidden" id="thestorehours">The store hours...</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Rory McCrossan. Works exactly as intended and is alot more cleaner as I wanted. Champion! :-)